# Allow editors to post iframes

Tags: user-roles, iframe

I just found out that editors are not allowed to post iframes (e.g. YouTube videos). Is it possible to allow it somehow? I use WP Multisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the iframe shortcode plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iframe/

> Embed iframe using shortcode [iframe
>   src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/819138" width="100%" height="480"]

ps: you can also use the default oembed shortcode:

```
[embed width="123" height="456"]...[/embed]
```

it supports YouTube, Vimeo, DailyMotion, Flickr, Twitter, ... and more.

Example:

```
[embed width="600" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTDNLUzjkpg[/embed]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

See more here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Comment: I don’t know why but the `[embed]` code doesn’t work …

Comment: whats the code you use?

Comment: what about e.g. [embed width="600" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTDNLUzjkpg[/embed]

Comment: Ah, my fault, I had a wrong YouTube link … Thanks!

Comment: ok great, hopefully this answered you question ;-)